# Local truncation error of Euler method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method#Local_truncation_error) and [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=hXebSBOmWqQC&pg=PA333&dq=%22local%20truncation%20error%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ykUMVLTgEOfmyQOll4GYDw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=%22It%20can%20be%20shown%20that%20the%20local%20truncation%20error%20is%20O(h2)%22&f=false) say the [local truncation error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_error_(numerical_integration)) of Euler method is $O(h^2)$. But [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=eGDMSIqPYdYC&pg=PA488&dq=local%20truncation%20error%20of%20euler%20method%20is%20O(h)&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IV0MVNWpE6S6ygPPsYGIBg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22this%20expression%20is%20linear%20in%20h%2C%20i.e.%2C%20di%3DO(h)%22&f=false) and A friendly Introduction to Numerical Analysis say it's $O(h)$. Which is correct? I have a similar problem with [implicit trapezoidal method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921407/order-of-implicit-trapezoidal-heuns-method).

**EDIT**

My numerical investigation shows that the LTE of Euler's method is $O(h^2)$. But I cannot understand why those texts say it is $O(h)$. For example for the ODE
$$
y^{\prime}(x)=1+y/x,\qquad y(6-h)=Y(6-h)
$$ 
where $Y$ is the exact solution of the ODE and $h=\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{16}$ at $x=6$ by using only **one step of Euler's method** we have

$$
\begin{array}{c, lcr}
h & \text{Approximate solution} & \text{Local truncation error} & \text{Error rato}\\
\hline
1/2  & 16.728488553430552 & 0.022068261937779 \\
1/4  & 16.745199128855553 & 0.005357686512777 & 4.118990 \\
1/8  & 16.749236360181335 & 0.001320455186995 & 4.057454 \\
1/16 & 16.750229016164560 & 0.000327799203770 & 4.028244
\end{array}
$$

As we see the step size is cut by a factor of $2$ and LTE decrease by a factor of $2^2$.

Comment: A local truncation error of [$O(h)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) would not do much good for computing an integral since dividing $h$ in half would produce an error for each step that is half, but then we need to sum up twice as many. For the method to converge, we would need better than $O(h)$. Perhaps the other book said that the LTE was [$o(h)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation), which *is* good enough to ensure convergence.

Comment: I just looked at the cited book, and it looks as if their $d_i$ is the LTE divided by $h$. So while $d_i=O(h)$, the LTE is $O(h^2)$.